Why does `[K in (keyof typeof SomeNumericEnum) as typeof SomeNumericEnum[K]]` result in the actual numerical index, rather than just `number`?
Given the following enum:
enum Animals {
  CAT,
  DOG,
  PARROT,
  SHEEP,
  SALMON
}

The following mapped type:
type AnimalsToMappedType = {
  [K in (keyof typeof Animals) as typeof Animals[K]]: K
}

Results in:
type AnimalsToMappedType = {
    0: "CAT";
    1: "DOG";
    2: "PARROT";
    3: "SHEEP";
    4: "SALMON";
}

QUESTION
Given that:
typeof Animals['DOG'] === 'number`

Why does [K in (keyof typeof Animals) as typeof Animals[K]] result in the actual numerical index, rather than just number?

typeof Animals['DOG'] is Animals.DOG, which is 1: https://tsplay.dev/mZKxDW. The runtime type is just a number, but the whole point of TypeScript is to provide type metadata for compile-time checking that simply isn't available in runtime JS.

typeof Animals["DOG"] === 'number' is JavaScript and has little to do with what  typeof Animals.DOG is in TS. TypeScript has the type number but it also has subtypes of number.  Are you aware of the existence of numeric literal types? Like type Foo = 0 | 1 | 2? If not, then that's why you get the "actual numerical" index. If so, then where's the disconnect? The fact that enum values are subtypes of numeric literal types? Please [edit] to clarify.
